# как работает Facebook invite android

Tags: android, facebook-api

Я в своем приложении хочу рассылать `invite` друзьям. В коде  которые я привел ниже  я вызываю диалог, в нем выбираю друзей которым хочу отправить `invite` - в логах вижу `Invitation Sent Successfully` но друзьям в фейсбуке ничего не приходит. В моем понимании после отправки `invite` друзьям на фейсбуке (не важно с какого девайса они сидят) - должно прийти оповещения и нажав на которое их должно кинуть на страницу Play Market или ту страницу которую я указывал при регистрации App Link, но этого не происходит. С инфой на developers.facebook.com ознакомился но не нашол там как происходит получения моего `invite` другими пользователями. Если я не правильно понял механизм - просьба разъяснить мне этот момент!

```
        mInviteDialog.registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {
                    Toast.makeText(InviteActivity.this, "Invitation Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d("Result", "Cancelled");
                    Toast.makeText(InviteActivity.this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Log.d("Result", "Error " + exception.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(InviteActivity.this, "Error while inviting friends", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
            });

    if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
        AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                .setApplinkUrl("https://fb.me/bla-bla-bla").build();
        AppInviteDialog.show(InviteActivity.this, content);

    }
```

Comment: А что приходит в result параметре метода onSuccess? Какие поля и значения в этом бандле?

Comment: @xkor результатом выполнения строчки  result.getData().keySet() есть строка " didComplete "

Comment: ну тогда очень странно, могу только предположить что либо у вас апплинки на фейсбуке настроены в тестовом режиме (я не знаю есть ли такой на самом деле), либо друзья ваши на фейсбуке смотрели не во всех местах приглашение (на правах бреда)

Comment: @xkor ну я не только друзьям, но и себе на второй аккаунт пробовал отправлять, что бы удостовериться- ничего не приходит. Я ж правильно понимаю оно как обычное уведомление должно прийти? А по поводу апп линков - как определить в тестовом они у меня режиме или нет?

Comment: Как я написал выше, это были лишь предположения, сам я фейсбуком пользуюсь только для авторизации в других сервисах и где там могут быть приглашения не знаю. Как определить режим я тоже не знаю, с апп линками пока не сталкивался, может такого режима и вообще нет. В общем видимо ни чем вам помочь не могу

Comment: @xkor ну и на том спасибо.